# ISQL Connected but PHP script doesn't work

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc, isql

I have a problem while connecting MSSQL ODBC. I tried using ISQL and it shows result, but when I use PHP script, there is no result.

I am using Ubuntu server 12, and PHP Version 5.3.10-1

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the MSSQL port(1433) is accessible via your webserver, If the webserver not able to reach that port it through communication error. 
We had the same problem with Centos 7. We have given enough access to webserver(httpd). It worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question sir, it will help me

Comment: Can you please provide any more details? We are having the same issue, and unsure of the solution. From the same CentOS 7 server where httpd is running, I can connect to SQL Server with sqlcmd and with isql as well, but PHP app shows communication problem.